# spring security saml and OBSSOCookie

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

our company is using Oracle access system for SAML single sign on. I implemented spring security with Spring Security SAML library, it worked great until I just found one issue recently.
Oracle Access System is using OBSSOCookie as identifier, but when saml response post back, I have no way to retrieve this cookie.
Have a look at this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/callback")
public void callback(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    SAMLCredential credential = (SAMLCredential) authentication.getCredentials();
    try {
        XMLHelper.nodeToString(SAMLUtil.marshallMessage(credential.getAuthenticationAssertion()));
    } catch (MessageEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String nameID = credential.getNameID().getValue();
    List<Attribute> attributes = credential.getAttributes();
    JSONObject jso = new JSONObject();
    String uid;
    String employeeType="";
    String company_name="";
    String FirstName;
    String roles_entitled="";
    String LastName;
    String primary_role="";


    jso.put("nameID", nameID);
    jso.put("uid", uid);
    jso.put("company_name", company_name);
    jso.put("roles_entitled", roles_entitled);
    jso.put("primary_role", primary_role);
    jso.put("employeeType", employeeType);
    jso.put("FirstName", FirstName);
    jso.put("LastName", LastName);

    String frontend_url = sideCarService.getFrontendNodeUrl();
    String token = KeyGenerator.createUserToken(jso, 3600 * 24 * 30);

    String encoded = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(jso.toString().getBytes()));
    response.sendRedirect(frontend_url + "#t/" + token + "/atts/" + encoded);
}
```

Looking at this code, I can  retrieve all the info from saml response, then generate a token, giving back to frontend cookie for use.

But I really want to get OBSSOCookie, so that I can use with other microservice to retrieve data from other applicaiton which is using same saml login solution.

I tried to user request.getHeaders(), but response is empty. No OBSSOCookie at all.

Any idea for how to obtain OBSSOCookie from spring saml library?

Thanks

Comment: You're going to need to use the OAM SDK to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the cookie is available to Spring SAML during validation of the SAML Response sent from IDP you can use the following approach.

Extend class `WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl` and implement method `processAdditionalData` which should return value of the `OBSSOCookie`. You can access the HTTP request and its HTTP headers/cookies through the `SAMLMessageContext` which is provided as a parameter.

The value you return will then be available under `additionalData` field in the `SAMLCredential` - which is indented for exactly these kinds of use-cases.